# Is there a place where a set of code is run every time I visit a route and the output of the code is available to the module at the route?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a web application that hosts several tools. E.g. docx-to-pdf, pdf-to-docx, etc... each is a vue module file within the application.

When the user goes to the docx-to-pdf tool, uploads the file using a dropzone, the server's file manager will generate a uuid (I call it a module session id) and use this as the directory name to place the uploaded file and return the uuid to the browser. Then when the user clicks on 'convert', the uuid is sent with the 'convert' command and the server will perform the conversion and allows the user to download the converted file.

This works fine until I have a tool called combine-pdf and have 2 dropzones on the page. When I'm uploading file1 in dropzone1 and file2 in dropzone2 at the same time, each goes into its own directory because the server's file manager thinks they're the first file to be uploaded. Unless I complete file1's upload first before I start file2, otherwise when I try click on 'combine', the server will only have one of the two uuids and will try to combine but only find one file there.

The most logical solution I can think of would be to generate the uuid in Vue, and when I upload files to the server, it'll validate that it's a proper uuid and use this throughout the session in this module. I can put this is Vue's created hook. This is fine but I find that as me or my teammates add modules, we keep repeating this same code in every module which seems repetitive.

Is there a place where I can generate this uuid and eventually pass it to the module's data so it's write once but every module gets a new uuid?

I thought of having a parent module for all these tool modules and in this parent module I would perform this uuid generation in its created hook but this is only loaded once and not every time I visit a module.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the the fileUpload function to the dropzone parent so that each dropzone component emits the file to the parent. The parent can then upload both files as an array to the server, and return an array of uuids to the client.